# Async method is working as syncronous mehtod

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am trying to call a async method of ViewModel from another method in View but it is behaving as syncronous.

View Model:

```
public async Task<bool> GetReadyForUnlockWithQR()
    {
        try
        {
            SmilaHash = GetRandomeHashKey();
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetSmilaInfo());
            var res = await apiClient.PostAsync<String>("readyforunlockwithqr", data);
            if (res != null)
            {
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(res);
                if (json["doUnlock"] != null)
                {
                    LoginStatus = json.SelectToken("doUnlock").Value<bool>();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            CancelPendingRequests();
            throw ex;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have my api methods defined in a custome APIClient file. The above request may take a minute to complete. I don't want to stop the UI and perform my further operations in View. Following is my View:

```
private async void UnlockButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR();
            DisplayQRCode();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is HttpRequestException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Server not reachable");
                MessageBox.Show("Server not reachable");
            }
            else if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Timeout exception");
                QRCodeImage.Source = null;
                QRCodeCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I above code ideally the DisplayQRCode() function should work immediately after await ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR(); but it is not happening. The DisplayQRCode() is waiting to receive response from ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR() Why is this not behaving as logical asyn code.

Comment: *"The DisplayQRCode() is waiting to receive response from ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR()"* - Because you are using `await` when calling the `async` operation.  Did you not want to do that?

Comment: No, I don't want to wait, the response can take over minute to arrive

Comment: You must not remove `await`. Just call `DisplayQRCode()` *before* `await ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR();`. See [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for an introduction. This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14455293/1136211

Comment: Why did you tag this as both ASP.NET and WPF? And I'm not a desktop developer...but isn't MessageBox specific to Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The DisplayQRCode() is waiting to receive response from ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR() Why is this not behaving as logical asyn code.

The asynchronous method is behaving serially (not "synchronously"), which is exactly what `await` is *supposed* to do.

You can think of `await` as "asynchronous wait": the method is paused and will not continue pass the `await` until the task completes, but it waits asynchronously, so the thread is freed (the method returns to its caller).

> I above code ideally the DisplayQRCode() function should work immediately after await ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR(); but it is not happening.

If you want to do that, then you can call `GetReadyForUnlockWithQR` but *don't* `await` the task until after `DisplayQRCode` completes:

```
var getReadyTask = ViewModel.GetReadyForUnlockWithQR();
DisplayQRCode();
await getReadyTask;
```